# Keycloak: Cluster mode distributed session owners not working

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, keycloak, session-state

We are running keycloak deployment as a cluster on Docker, lately facing the issue where if one node goes down which is the associated sessions for that particular node get logged out. As per the documentation for Keycloak it mentioned that

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:12.0">
   <cache-container name="keycloak">
       <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2"/>
```

Should take care of the problem however it still does not solve the issue, if the node is taken down the associated sessions just get logged out.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the settings below

```
<cache-container name="keycloak">.
```

It should say something like this:

```
<replicated-cache name="work"/>
<distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="1"/>
<distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="1"/>
<distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="1"/>
<distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="1"/>
<distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="1"/>
<distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="1"/>
<distributed-cache name="actionTokens" owners="1">
```

Make sure that "sessions" it is not overwritten and put the "2" in "owners" in all of them.

Restart keycloak.